# When does $(x+y)^n+(x-y)^n\leq(2x)^n$ hold?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

With $n\in\mathbb{N}$, what is the relation between $(x+y)^n+(x-y)^n\leq(2x)^n$ and the values of $x$ and $y$?

Or mathematically: $(x+y)^n+(x-y)^n\leq(2x)^n\iff$ the values of $x$ and $y$ are such that what?

I believe that $(x+y)^n+(x-y)^n\leq(2x)^n\implies{x}\geq{y}\geq0$.

But it's a partial answer, and I'm not even sure about that...

Thanks

Comment: Can you not expand and check the condition when the exponent of the terms with respect to y and -y are even? As the other case the terms cancel?

Comment: @Chinny84: I'm not so sure, that's why I asked. Half of the terms are cancelled anyway (whether $n$ is even or odd), but I'm not sure about the implications of that. In general, I'm interested in knowing, for example, if $(8+3)^n+(8-3)^n\leq(2\cdot8)^n$.

Comment: Have you tried considering the contrapositive statement? ($P \implies Q$ is the same as $\bar{Q} \implies \bar{P}$)

Comment: What I meant $$(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\matrix{ n \\ k}\right)x^ky^{n-k}$$ the terms that have $n-k$ that are odd cancel.

Comment: @YiyuanLee: No  (since I've never heard of it).

Comment: @Chinny84: What I meant is, the other terms (which consist half of all terms) are **not** cancelled, hence I still need to consider them in order to determine the conditions under which the inequity holds.

Comment: If it holds for $y$, it holds for $-y$, so the domain can't be $x \ge y \ge 0$, it has to be symmetric around zero.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: That's what I meant by stating that it's probably a partial answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $x$ is positive and set $z=\frac{y}{x}$. Then you are asking for which values of $z\in\mathbb{R}$ we have:
$$ f_n(z) = (1+z)^n+(1-z)^n \leq 2^n. $$
Well, $f(z)$ is a convex even function and equality is attained in the endpoints of the interval $I=[-1,1]$, hence $f_n(z)\leq 2^n$ holds if and only if $z\in I$, i.e. $|y|\leq x$.

If $x$ is negative and $n$ is even the situation is the same, yielding $|y|\leq |x|$.

If $x$ is negative and $n$ is odd we have a concave function ($(-1-z)^n+(-1+z)^n$), yielding the reverse inequality $|y|\geq |x|$.